# Which components of the linear and angular momentum are conserved in the following situation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws

A particle moves on a gravitational potential produced by the distribution of mass on a sphere of radius R.

First I calculated the lagrangian:

$T=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}+\dot{z}^{2})$

$V=-\frac{GM}{R}$

$L=T-V=\frac{m}{2}(\dot{x}^{2}+\dot{y}^{2}+\dot{z}^{2})+\frac{GM}{R}$

Next I used the general formula for the linear momentum:

$P_{i}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{r}_{i}}$

The three components of the linear momentum are:

$P_{x}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}=m\dot{x}$

$P_{y}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{y}}=m\dot{y}$

$P_{z}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{z}}=m\dot{z}$

To check whether or not the components of P are conserved, I calculated their derivatives

$\frac{dP_{i}}{dt}=\dot{P}_{i}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{i}}$

$\dot{P}_{x}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$

$\dot{P}_{y}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=0$

$\dot{P}_{z}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial z}=0$

Since the derivatives are all equal to zero, they are all conserved

Did I do it right?

How would I do the same thing for angular momentum?

Comment: Is the particle constrained to move on the sphere of radius $R$? If so, there wouldn't be $3$ independent generalized coordinates, there would be only $2$.

Comment: Remember R is a function of x, y, and z, so your Lagrangian is not in fact independent of x, y, and z. This makes sense, as the momentum of an individual body in a gravitational field is clearly not conserved, only the momentum of the system as a whole.

Comment: @MC2k depends. Since R was declared to be radius of the surface, the lagrangian suggests the movement is constraint to the sphere, were R is just a constant and generalized momenta indeed should be conserved.

Comment: @Umaxo the linear momentum of the particle is most certainly not conserved even in the constrained case To make this clear, approximate the earth's orbit as circular, and then I think you will very quickly see the drastic consequences of conserved momenta.

Comment: @random name
Were you asked to solve this by using a Lagrangian? Because if not one may want to use a central force argument for the angular momentum

Comment: @MC2K I was talking about generalized momentum not linear.